# Meteor Easy Search Pagination Integration

Tags: meteor

I'm using the meteor-easy-search package to integrate search and pagination into my application:
https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search

I have it working, sorta. The search works like a charm, however the pagination is pretty buggy. I want to show 25 results per page. If there are less than 25 results, obviously all of those results should show on the first page. If there are say 70 results, the first page should show 25, the second page 25 and the third page 20.

What's currently happening is page 1 may be randomly blank, page 2 shows like 8 records, and page 3 will show the remainder. And not always in that order. Page 1 may show 15 records, with page 2 and page 3 showing the remainder. Also, I'm trying to sort results by date with most recent appearing first. That is also not working correctly. It appears to work for the first portion of the results however at the end the results there will be a random entries that are out of place.

I have a feeling my implementation is off somewhere, causing these odd and random issues. Can someone take a look please and let me know what I've done wrong?

In client:

```
    Template.history.rendered = function () {

      var instance = EasySearch.getComponentInstance(
        { id : 'search', index : 'items' }
      );
      EasySearch.changeLimit('items', 25);
      EasySearch.pagination('items', EasySearch.PAGINATION_NEXT); // Go to the second step
    };
```

Both on client and server:

```
    Items = new Mongo.Collection("items");

    EasySearch.createSearchIndex('items', {
      'collection': Items,
      'field': ["details","createdAt"],
      'limit': 10,
      'use' : 'mongo-db',
      'props': {
        'sortBy': 'asc'
      },
      'sort': function() {
        if (this.props.sortBy === 'asc') {
          return { 'createdAt': -1 };
        }
      },
      'query': function(searchString, opts) {
        var query = EasySearch.getSearcher(this.use).defaultQuery(this, searchString);
        return query;
      }
    });
```

In the history html template:

```
      {{> esInput allDocsOnEmpty=true index="items" id="search" placeholder="Search now..." }}
      {{> esPagination index="items" id="search" }}

      {{#esEach index="items" id="search"}}
        {{#if isOwner username }}
      <tr style="height: 150px;">
        <td>{{ username }}</td>
        <td>{{ formatTime createdAt }}</td>
        <td> {{ details }} </td>
      </tr>
        {{/if}}
      {{/esEach}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Off hand I do not have an exact solution but I think you have defined 2 limits. One in the index and the other for results but I do think they may conflict? 25 and 10?